# Issues using jQuery DataTable function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I've been attempting to get laravel-datatables to work for the past two days.

I am trying to fetch a list of users to the datatable and got all the backend stuff working. However I keep getting issues with the jQuery datatables plugin. After googling the issue I only found solutions in regards to wrong load order. However I do load jQuery before I load the datatables plugins, so I've got a hard time seeing why it fails the way it does.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#student-datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "{{ route('data.get.students') }}",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "name" }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Results in the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (students:90)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)
```

And the load order is as follows

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

I expect the function to get the response from Ajax and display it in a DataTable to make it easier to view for others.

Comment: Try with lower case 'D' :  $('#student-datatable').dataTable(...)

Comment: This seems to be laravel related issue, what version of laravel and laravel-datatables are you using? Have you followed these steps: https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master?

Comment: Rabi:
That didn't sadly resolve the issue.
barbsan:
Yes I've followed that guide and I'm using 9.0 of laravel-datatables.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue myself. Figured that jQuery already comes with Laravel 5.8 and is compiled into the app.js file. Other thing is that the "defer" attribute forces the app.js to be loaded after the page is done loading. Meaning the datatables plugin would load before jQuery itself.

**Solution**

Remove the defer attribute and move the script to just before the  tag, but before the datatable plugin. So the new script would look like the following.

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```